# Summary output to independent dataset

Tags: r

Im working with a twitter dataset i got with rtweet. I worked to create a state variable based on the coordinates (when available). 
my output is this so far

```
> summary(rt1$state)
             alabama              arizona             arkansas           california             colorado          connecticut 
                   3                    6                    2                  104                    5                    1 
            delaware district of columbia              florida              georgia                idaho             illinois 
                   1                    0                   17                    7                    0                   12 
             indiana                 iowa               kansas             kentucky            louisiana                maine 
                   4                    1                    2                    3                    2                    1 
            maryland        massachusetts             michigan            minnesota          mississippi             missouri 
                   1                    2                    9                    6                    0                    2 
             montana             nebraska               nevada        new hampshire           new jersey           new mexico 
                   0                    3                    5                    1                    4                    7 
            new york       north carolina         north dakota                 ohio             oklahoma               oregon 
                  25                    8                    1                    3                    2                    4 
        pennsylvania         rhode island       south carolina         south dakota            tennessee                texas 
                  22                    0                    2                    1                    3                   35 
                utah              vermont             virginia           washington        west virginia            wisconsin 
                   2                    1                    3                    5                    0                    2 
             wyoming                 NA's 
                   1                17669
```

can you please advise on how can i create an independent dataset from the output above so i have 2 columns (state and n) ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap with `stack` to create a two column `data.frame` from the OP's code

```
out <- stack(summary(rt1$state))[2:1]
names(out) <- c("state", "n")
```

---

Or another option in `base R` is

```
as.data.frame(table(rt1$state))
```

A reproducible example

```
data(iris)
out <- stack(summary(iris$Species))[2:1]
```

Or with `table`

```
as.data.frame(table(iris$Species))
```

---

Or `enframe` from `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(summary(rt1$state)) %>%
   unnest(c(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you can work directly on your `rt1` dataframe:

```
dplyr::count(rt1, state)
```